# symfony FMElfinder bundle multiple fileselect

Tags: php, symfony, elfinder

i searched every where for this feature and i couldn't find the right config to do this.
when i select one file the select icon is enabled but when i select more, it becomes disabled.

i expected the elfinder to let me select more than one file and return an array of selected files.

but it always gives me one file.

this is the config for form instance :

```
fm_elfinder:

instances:
    form:
                locale: %locale%
                editor: form 
                fullscreen: true 
                include_assets: true
                connector:
                    debug: false 
                    roots:      
                        uploads:
                            driver: LocalFileSystem
                            path: uploads
                            alias: "uploads"
                            upload_allow: ['all']
                            upload_deny:
                            upload_max_size: 4000M
```

Comment: i already tried changing the commandsOptions multiple to true,but when i do that the select option only becomes enabled and does nothing.not even when i select only 1 file.

Comment: Hi, did you by any chance find a solution to this problem?